# Why PyTorch nn.Module.cuda() not moving Module tensor but only parameters and buffers to GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, tensor

`nn.Module.cuda()` moves all model parameters and buffers to the GPU.

But why not the model member tensor?

```
class ToyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(ToyModule, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.expected_moved_cuda_tensor = torch.tensor([0, 2, 3])

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.layer(input)

toy_module = ToyModule()
toy_module.cuda()
```

```
next(toy_module.layer.parameters()).device
>>> device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

for the model member tensor, the device stays unchanged.

```
>>> toy_module.expected_moved_cuda_tensor.device
device(type='cpu')
```

Answer (score 12):

If you define a tensor inside the module it needs to be registered as either a parameter or a buffer so that the module is aware of it.

---

*Parameters* are tensors that are to be trained and will be returned by `model.parameters()`. They are easy to register, all you need to do is wrap the tensor in the `nn.Parameter` type and it will be automatically registered. Note that only floating point tensors can be parameters.

```
class ToyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(ToyModule, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2)
        # registering expected_moved_cuda_tensor as a trainable parameter
        self.expected_moved_cuda_tensor = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0., 2., 3.]))

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.layer(input)
```

---

*Buffers* are tensors that will be registered in the module so methods like `.cuda()` will affect them but they will *not* be returned by `model.parameters()`. Buffers are not restricted to a particular data type.

```
class ToyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(ToyModule, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2)
        # registering expected_moved_cuda_tensor as a buffer
        # Note: this creates a new member variable named expected_moved_cuda_tensor
        self.register_buffer('expected_moved_cuda_tensor', torch.tensor([0, 2, 3])))

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.layer(input)
```

---

In both of the above cases the following code behaves the same

```
>>> toy_module = ToyModule()
>>> toy_module.cuda()
>>> next(toy_module.layer.parameters()).device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
>>> toy_module.expected_moved_cuda_tensor.device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```